# How to use OneHotEncoder for multiple columns and automatically drop first dummy variable for each column?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

This is the dataset with 3 cols and 3 rows

> **Name    Organization    Department**
>
> Manie     ABC2    FINANCE
>
> Joyce     ABC1    HR
>
> Ami   NSV2    HR

This is the code I have:

Now it is fine till here, how do i drop the first dummy variable column for each ?

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data1.csv',encoding = "cp1252")
X = dataset.values


# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_0 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_0.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = "all")
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Comment: pandas has `get_dummies()`, which has a parameter `drop_first` you can set to True. Here's an example of using get_dummies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43971156/1870832

Comment: Hey Max Power, I tried X = pd.get_dummies(X, drop_first=True)), but its showing an error SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: see my answer below and tested output. I'm guessing your syntax error is from another part of your code.

Comment: Max, I tried urcode and it works, but when i replace df with X, it throws as error. This is probably because X is not in the form of a dataframe, since I have imported the csv into dataset and then later taken X = dataset.iloc[:, :].values. I've done this because this is a part of a much larger project and i have simplified for stackoverflow. I willl need to split the dataset into X and y

Comment: your X comes in from `read_csv` as a Pandas DatafFrame. try passing that `dataset` to `pd.get_dummies()` before taking `.values`. If you want the one-hot-encoded output to be a numpy array, you can take `.values` of the output of `pd.get_dummies`

Comment: Thanks a lot Max Power. You're amazing!

Comment: happy to help. good luck with the rest of the project.

Comment: Please let me know how to select particular columns by indexes. I want to drop the first column and am trying x = pd.get_dummies(X, columns =[1:],drop_first=True), but its not working.

Comment: see my updated answer. sorry for the delay, I think we're in different timezones, I went to asleep.

Comment: Yes we are in different timezones :-)... Thanks for ur reply..  Wish u a pleasant weekend.

Comment: See my answer below. You can use OneHotEncoder starting sklearn version 0.21.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Manie', 'Joyce', 'Ami'],
                   'Org':  ['ABC2', 'ABC1', 'NSV2'],
                   'Dept': ['Finance', 'HR', 'HR']        
        })


df_2 = pd.get_dummies(df,drop_first=True)
```

test:

```
print(df_2)
   Dept_HR  Org_ABC2  Org_NSV2  name_Joyce  name_Manie
0        0         1         0           0           1
1        1         0         0           1           0
2        1         0         1           0           0
```

---

UPDATE regarding your error with `pd.get_dummies(X, columns =[1:]`:

Per the [documentation page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), the `columns` parameter takes "Column Names". So the following code would work:

```
df_2 = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Org', 'Dept'], drop_first=True)
```

output:

```
    name  Org_ABC2  Org_NSV2  Dept_HR
0  Manie         1         0        0
1  Joyce         0         0        1
2    Ami         0         1        1
```

If you really want to define your columns positionally, you could do it this way:

```
column_names_for_onehot = df.columns[1:]
df_2 = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=column_names_for_onehot, drop_first=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

I use my own template for doing that:

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
class DataFrameEncoder(TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        """Encode the data.

        Columns of data type object are appended in the list. After 
        appending Each Column of type object are taken dummies and 
        successively removed and two Dataframes are concated again.

        """
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.object_col = []
        for col in X.columns:
            if(X[col].dtype == np.dtype('O')):
                self.object_col.append(col)
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        dummy_df = pd.get_dummies(X[self.object_col],drop_first=True)
        X = X.drop(X[self.object_col],axis=1)
        X = pd.concat([dummy_df,X],axis=1)
        return X
```

And for using this code just put this template in current directory with filename let's suppose CustomeEncoder.py and type in your code:

```
from customEncoder import DataFrameEncoder
data = DataFrameEncoder().fit_transormer(data)
```

And all the object type data removed, Encoded, removed first and joined together to give the final desired output.
PS: That the input file to this template is Pandas Dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite simple in scikit-learn version starting from 0.21. One can use the drop parameter in OneHotEncoder and use it to drop one of the categories per feature. By default, it won't drop. Details can be found in documentation.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder

```
//drops the first category in each feature
ohe = OneHotEncoder(drop='first', handle_unknown='error')
```

Answer (score 1):

I use my own module for dealing with one hot encoding.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class My_encoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
   
    def __init__(self,drop = 'first',sparse=False):
        self.encoder = OneHotEncoder(drop = drop,sparse = sparse)
        self.features_to_encode = []
        self.columns = []
    
    def fit(self,X_train,features_to_encode):
        
        data = X_train.copy()
        self.features_to_encode = features_to_encode
        data_to_encode = data[self.features_to_encode]
        self.columns = pd.get_dummies(data_to_encode,drop_first = True).columns
        self.encoder.fit(data_to_encode)
        return self.encoder
    
    def transform(self,X_test):
        
        data = X_test.copy()
        data.reset_index(drop = True,inplace =True)
        data_to_encode = data[self.features_to_encode]
        data_left = data.drop(self.features_to_encode,axis = 1)
        
        data_encoded = pd.DataFrame(self.encoder.transform(data_to_encode),columns = self.columns)
        
        return pd.concat([data_left,data_encoded],axis = 1)
```

Its pretty easy to use

```
features_to_encode = [---list of features to one hot encode--]
enc = My_encoder()
enc.fit(X_train,features_to_encode)
X_train = enc.transform(X_train)
X_test = enc.transform(X_test)
```

It returns dataframe with columns names. So, covers both the disadvantages of OneHotEncoder and pd.get_dummies().
So, we can use it to fit and transform, like OneHotEncoder, and also it saves us the column names and returns a datafram like dummies approach.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the categorical variables one at a time. The dummy variables should go to the beginning index of your data set. Then, just cut off the first column like this:

```
X = X[:, 1:]
```

Then encode and repeat the next variable.

Answer (score 0):

Applying OneHotEncoder only to certain columns is possible with the ColumnTransformer.
Create a separate pipeline for categorical and numerical variable and apply ColumnTransformer. More info about it can be found here [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html).

Another great example of implementation of this is provided [here](https://adhikary.net/en/2019/03/23/categorical-and-numeric-data-in-scikit-learn-pipelines/).

Comment: Please write relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.

Answer (score -2):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
for i in range(Y.shape[1]):
    Y[:,i] = le.fit_transform(Y[:,i])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code-only answers aren't encouraged. Please also provide some context.

Comment: Please provide an explanation so others can understand your code, and learn how it solves the problem.