# LabelEncoding() vs OneHotEncoding() (sklearn,pandas) suggestions

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

I have 3 types of categorical data in my dataframe, `df`.

```
df['Vehicles Owned'] = [1,2,3+,2,1,2,3+,2]
df['Sex'] = ['m','m','f','m','f','f','m','m']
df['Income'] = [42424,65326,54652,9463,9495,24685,52536,23535]
```

What should I do for the `df['Vehicles Owned']` ? (one hot encode, labelencode or leave it as is by converting 3+ to integer. I have used integer values as they are. looking for the suggestions as there is order)

for `df['Sex']` , should I labelEncode it or One hot? ( as there is no order, I have used One Hot Encoding)

**`df['Income']` has lots of variations. so should I convert it to bins and use One Hot Encoding explaining `low`,`medium`,`high` incomes?**

Comment: Assuming a linear model, do you want owning 2(3) vehicles to have 2x(3x) the effect of owning 1 vehicle, or can the relationship be entirely independent? The answer to that determines if you want dummies or to encode the variable, though given 3+ I'm guessing dummies.

Comment: As a side note, in scikit-learn, you should not use `LabelEncoder` to encode `X`. `LabelEncoder` is only to encode `y`. The `OneHotEncoder` is the way to go. In scikit-learn 0.22, you have a new option `drop` which allow you to drop one of the column which is colinear with the rest of the feature encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend:

- For `sex`, one-hot encode, which translates to using a single boolean
  var for `is_female` or `is_male`; for n categories you need n-1
  one-hot-encoded vars because
  the nth is linearly dependent on the first n-1.
- For `vehicles_owned` if you want to preserve order, I would re-map
  your vars from `[1,2,3,3+]` to `[1,2,3,4]` and treat as an int var,
  or to `[1,2,3,3.5]` as a float var.
- For `income`: you should probably just leave that as a float var.
  Certain models (like GBT models) will likely do some sort of binning
  under the hood. If your income data happens to have an exponential
  distribution, you might try `log`ing it. But just converting it to
  bins in your own feature-engineering is not what I'd recommend.

Meta-advice for all these things is set up a cross-validation scheme you're confident in, try different formulations for all your feature-engineering decisions, and then follow your cross-validated performance measure to make your ultimate decision.

Finally, between which library/function to use I prefer pandas' `get_dummies` because it allows you to keep column-names informative in your final feature-matrix like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43971156/1870832

Comment: yes, I use ```get_dummies``` with ```drop_first=True``` and thanks for the advice, Max